# How did the Dvaitavadi Vaishnavas explain the brahma sutra that says Pancharatra is wrong?

Tags: vaishnavism, brahma-sutras

According to the Brahma-Sutra 2/2/42, the PAncharAtra/BhAgavata doctrines are not acceptable.

How did the Dvaitavadi (Non-Advaitavadi) Vaishnava Acharyas who followed the Pancharatra/Bhagavata doctrines explain this? Answer could be from the ancient Acharyas any school of Dvaita-vaada.

Comment: Just look at Madhva bhashya.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Sorry for a common man like me, a look is not enough

Answer (score 4):

Sri Madhvacharya believes Brahma Sutras Adhyaya 2 Pada 2 Verses 42-45 talks about Shaktism rather than Pancharatra Agamas:

> 42. On account of the impossibility of origination, 
>       {Sakti, a Goddess, cannot be the cause).
>
> **Commentary:** For the bringing forth of anything has not been observed on the part of the female without the favour 
>   of the male.
>
> 43. Nor it there the necessary instrumentality of organs 
>       for the (supposed male) agent.
>
> **Commentary:** Even if a male agent be admitted to be (her helper) 
>   the impossibility of origination would still remain unexplained ; for the agent would be wanting means or organs (i.e., wisdom, the body and organs); and it is not possible 
>   that he is of any help to her in the work of creation.
>
> 44. Further if wisdom, etc. be alto supposed (for him), 
>       there is no denying of that; (then the system lapses into the Pasupata).
>
> **Commentary:** If wisdom and the necessary organs be supposed to 
>   be possessed by the Purusha (Sadasiva), then from him 
>   alone origination, etc., may proceed and there appears no 
>   necessity (again) for attributing them to Sakti. Further 
>   according to the position lastly assumed, the system 
>   would be included under the Pasupata and is consequently open to the objections taken to it.
>
> 45. And on account of its being contradictory to (the 
>       Vedic conclusions).
>
> **Commentary:** As this system is opposed to (and condemned by) 
>   all the Srutis and Smritis, and abhorred by the wise, it is 
>   not worthy of regard.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Do you need the Gaudiya Vaishnava interpretation too?

Comment: of course if its by Sri Rupa, Sri Sanatana or Sri Jiva

Comment: @Pratimaputra None of them wrote a commentary on the Brahma Sutras.  But Baladeva Vidyabhushana did.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan thnx.yes i know.But Sri Baladeva wrote certain things to establish that the Gaudiyas are a part of the Madhvas which contradict Mahaprabhu's teachings.These were discussed by Gaudiya scholars in1937 and 1953.So i am not interested in his explanations.In Bengal there have been many detailed researches on Mahaprabhu since early 20th century.